# how can I check for length of the url string of a google DFP call?

Tags: google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I need to pass a bunch of custom parameters into a Google DFP ad call. If the ad request is over 2,000 characters, some parameters passed into it get truncated. I would like to know how many characters the current call would take and manually truncate some of the values, instead of Google doing it for me. How can I get the length of the call?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old question, but I had this same problem along with several other questions about the URL a few months ago, so thought I would share.

Add the following to your code before the the display call.
What this does is:

```
/**
 * ##logUrl
 * Logs the ID of the ad and the length of its URL at render time.
 * @param {Event} e - GPT's slotRenderEnded event.
 */
logUrl = function(e) {
  var str = e.slot.getSlotId().getDomId() +
  ' URL length: ' + e.slot.getContentUrl().length;
  console.log(str);
}

googletag.cmd.push(function () {
  googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', logUrl);
});
```

## Explanation

- **slotRenderEnded**: This event fires just after the ad's Iframe is constructed.
- **slot**: Returns everything google knows about this ad.
- **getSlotId**: Returns the slot's long identifier from the googletag object.
- **getDomId**:  Returns the html ID of this ad's container.
- **getContentUrl**: Returns the URL we want.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this with jQuery would be to do:

`var dfpRequestLength = jQuery('script[src*="gampad/ads"]').attr('src').length;`

This assumes a lot, but works on our DFP instance.